# PHP how to select specific SQL cell and store in variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

The Login system worked for Username and Password however when trying to check the Type field for that exact Username and Password (so cannot simply select a row as this will vary) and loading a different page depending on Type my code does not work...I assume I require a different sort of SQL function in my PHP.

Code:

```
require_once('connection.php');
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from Staff WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
        $numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        $type = mysql_query("SELECT Type from Staff WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");


        if ($numRows==1){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["loggedin"]=$username;
            if ($type = "admin"){
                $url = 'url.../loggedinAdmin.php' ?>
                    <script language = "JavaScript">
                        parent.location.href = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
                    </script>
            <?php }else if ($type = 'student'){
                $url = 'url.../loggedinStudent.php' ?>
                    <script language = "JavaScript">
                        parent.location.href = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
                    </script>
            <?php }else{
                $errors .= "There is no such user. Try again or contact admin. <br/>";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Because Type is reserved name. Use grave accent **`Type`** with Your column name</del>

**UPDATE 4**

**Type** is not reserved name. My strange mistake when I tested.

HINT:

Don't use `mysql_*` extension. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. 
U can use `mysql_query(...) or die( mysql_error() );` to see whats wrong with your sql statement if fail.

**UPDATE 2**

You have mistake in

`if ($type = "admin"){`

change to

`if ($type == "admin"){`

and

`if ($type = "student"){`

to

`if ($type == "student"){`

**UPDATE 3**

```
$rh = mysql_query("SELECT `Type` from Staff WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rh );
$type = $row['Type'];
```

Comment: Changed column name to UserType and it works for admin yet somehow doesn't work for non-existent users or Student...

Comment: Or change column name. But if u use reserved name like AS, TYPE etc. You must use grave accent with it. For example \`Type`

Comment: I have, thank you. I have a feeling the issue lies with the $userType=mysql_query... as the login Student does not work. I tried changing it by checking the Username and it did work however so this seems like the only issue. Is there any specific function where I can check the UserType for a specific Username and Password?

Comment: `type` is **not** a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - you should modify your answer and remove that statement. The actual problem is `if ($type = 'student')` -`if ($type = "admin")` where OP is assigning instead of comparing `==`. You should refer to the MySQL website first, before saying it is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right . Strange behavior. I did not look into doc, but try sql in mysql console. It fail. As i always do - try my answers.